# How to include type definitions in js library bundled with esbuild

Tags: typescript, npm, esbuild

I am working on a JS library to be published in npm with TypeScript and esbuild. My esbuild command successfully minifies all of my .ts files into a single .js file. The problem is there are no type definitions, so if I publish just the .js file, there won't be type definitions for users of my library. How can I configure esbuild to include type definitions.

Side note: Do I have to worry about publishing different flavors of JS by import/module/es5 or...? I just want the library to be used by everyone.